# Symmetrize seems to be stuck on the wrong axis

Tags: rigging, mirror

I am very new to blender and cannot formulate the question well enough for google to help me. I am just trying to flip my bones around to the other half of my model but I'm getting this issue where it's not flipping across the right axis. Instead of mirroring across my model it does it in front of it. I cannot find a setting to change this and when I rotate the whole model it still does it in a local sense. I am not sure how else to manipulate blender's settings to get it to do what I want. I was watching a tutorial and it seemingly just worked fine for the guy teaching it. [image: Bones being mirrored across the Y axis instead of the X axis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetrize operation will happen on the Y local axis, your armature is not correctly oriented. You should also align your armature to the *Global* front view. So in *Object* mode, rotate your armature 90° on the Z axis, apply its scale and rotation and symmetrize again.